# fast bubble sort

Tags: python, sorting

```
def bubble(lst):
    swap = 'True'
    counter = 0
    n = len(lst)
    m = len(lst)
    while swap == 'True':
            for j in range(n-1):
                    if lst[j] > lst[j+1]:
                            lst[j],lst[j+1] = lst[j+1],lst[j]
                            counter += 1
                            swap = 'True'
                    else:
                            swap = 'False'
            n = n - 1
    return counter
```

How do I shorten the time this function takes because I want to use it on a larger list.

Comment: There is nothing called "fast bubble sort" from my point of view, bubble sort is slow by definition, it's O(n * n)!!!!

Comment: http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/

Comment: i know there isn't it was just a title to say what I want from the program. But I've been told there is a way to make the bubble sort run more quickly where it does not go through the loop unnecessarily

Comment: If your goal is just to sort a list, a very efficient algorithm is built into Python.  Just call `lst.sort()`.

Comment: There's a bug in your current version. swap = 'False' should be in front of the for-loop. Right now, only the last comparison determines the value of swap. Meaning if you swap a lot but not the last two items, your algorithm stops anyway, way ahead of time.

Comment: Why on earth do you use `'True'` and `'False'` instead of `True` and `False`?

Answer (score 3):

Change algorithm.

Use MergeSort or QuickSort.

BubbleSort is O(n*n).
The only reason it exists is to show students how they should not sort arrays :)

MergeSort is worst case O(n log n).

QuickSort is O(n * n) worst case, average case O(n log n), but with "low constants", so it's usually faster than merge sort.

Search for them on the web.

If i'm not wrong... (don't rage at me if I am please)... I think I understood what you want to do:

```
def bubble(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    while True
        newn = 0
        for i in range(1, n-1):
            if lst[i-1] > lst[i]:
                lst[i-1],lst[i] = lst[i],lst[i-1]
                newn = i
                counter += 1
        if newn <= 0:
            return counter
        n = newn
```

The complexity however will be always O(n * n) so you will not notice any important difference.

For example:

If your list is 2000 items and you use bubble sort, O(2000 * 2000) = 4000000 loop steps. This is huge.

O(2000 * log2 2000) = about 21931 of loop steps, and this is manageable.